# Unlocking Bootloader on Motorola ET1

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock

I would like to unlock the bootloader on my Motorola ET1, but I have a problem: once I restart the device in the bootloader, it is not recognized by my computer (`fastboot devices` doesn't detect it) and therefore I cannot complete the process.

Why is this? I have the Android SDK installed on my Windows 10 Pro x64 PC, and the drivers are installed as well because I am able to use adb-based commands just fine.

Here's what I am doing to try to get the bootloader.

I connect the device to my computer and use the Android SDK to issue `adb reboot bootloader` which causes the device to restart and boot in to this screen.

[image: Bootloader Screen]

My device seems to be listed in the Device Manager no matter what state my device is in.

[image: Device Manager]

`fastboot devices` does not do anything when I run it.

[image: fastboot devices]

Comment: `fastboot devices` does not show the device. I am running Windows 10 Pro x64. Unfortunately, that is all the information I can provide at the moment because I do not have access to my computer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, David – I've integrated that with your question. Next thing to check: put the device in bootloader mode and connect it to your PC, then check with the device manager if it's shown there. Though your drivers work fine with ADB, devices often identify differently when in Fastboot, so the drivers might not "match" that.

Comment: @Izzy I have added the requested information to the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've readjusted them a bit to make your question easier to read (less scrolling), larger variants linked (click to see). Looks like the driver you're using doesn't cover Fastboot. I'm no Windows user, so I cannot help you much with that – but IMHO the "generic description" in device manager suggests there might be a driver from Google to match it.

Comment: @Izzy According to the SDK Manager, I have the latest USB Driver installed. The device that I am using is several years old. Could the issue have to do with the tablet being intended for corporate use?

Comment: I doubt the latter. But again: there's nothing like *the* driver. On Windows, drivers are specific to the device usually. So "the latest USB driver" might fit in ADB mode, but not in Fastboot mode. Not that the driver must be incompatible – it might just not feel "responsible" for the (different) ID the device reports in Fastboot mode. On Linux, I just had to check with `lsusb` and add the IDs to the config. I've got no idea about Windows, so someone else has to take over here.

Comment: @Izzy Okay, well, thanks for carrying me this far!